# Maximum Total Google Ads Per Page

Tags: adsense

I'm looking at my options for putting adverts on my website and thought I'd start with Google Adsense - However I'm unsure of exactly how many adverts you can actually have per page. I'm guessing it's OK to mix and match banners with say advert blocks, etc, etc - So what is the maximum total number you can have on a single page?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about advertising, not programming

Comment: This is about advertising, nothing to do with programming

Comment: @DavidKron,. The question was not posted under any programming tag. It was posted under some non-technical adsense tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Ad Placement policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_on_the_same_page_or_site_as_another_publisher), a `maximum of three standard ad units, three link units, and two search boxes may be placed on one webpage`

> Please keep in mind that a maximum of three standard ad units, three
>   link units, and two search boxes may be placed on one webpage. In
>   addition, please be aware that every publisher is responsible for the
>   content of a website on which their ad code is placed. If a website is
>   found in violation of our program policies, we will notify any
>   publisher(s) whose ad code is on the website, and ask you to remove
>   the Google code from that page.

They further clarify in this [question](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Google_ad_limit_per_page)

> Currently, AdSense publishers may place up to three AdSense for
>   content units on one webpage. This includes a maximum of one 300x600
>   ad unit per page. You may also place a maximum of three link units and
>   two search boxes on each webpage.

Comment: Ah right, So basically an overall total of 8 Adsense elements per web page? What exactly do the search boxes do from a search and financial point of view as I've not thought of using them before now?

Comment: This should help answer that [question](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/35873?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's a huge help - I guess for the space it takes up on a page it's worth dropping one in there somewhere

Comment: speedtest.net has 6 standard ad units on their home page.

Comment: So we are allowed to use 3 + 3 ads, or 3 ads in sum?

Comment: @DanFromGermany According that that page you can do a total of 8 on a page. 3 + 3 + 2 (search boxes)

Comment: @DanFromGermany is this number 3 excluded from Ads from other netowrks? Means if I put 3 ads from ADSENSE on my one page, can I still put more ads from other Ad networks ???

Comment: @Andy  is this number 3 excluded from Ads from other netowrks? Means if I put 3 ads from ADSENSE on my one page, can I still put more ads from other Ad networks ???

Comment: Accepted answer is no longer active: [Google removes AdSense 3-ads-per-page limit, focuses on content-to-ad balance](http://marketingland.com/google-removes-adsense-3-ads-per-page-limit-focuses-content-ad-balance-189064 "Google removes AdSense 3-ads-per-page limit, focuses on content-to-ad balance") Text quoted from [Ad placement policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_on_the_same_page_or_site_as_another_publisher) in accepted answer no longer exists

Answer (score 12):

[Google Adsense Ads Per Page Limit](http://bestparttimejob.in/google-adsense-ads-per-page-limit-lifted-big-adsense-policy-update/) has been lifted according to recent policy change. Google makes the publishers happy with this recent change. Now publishers can place more than 3 ads, which will eventually result into more income.

Answer (score 7):

Google removed the limit of three ads per page in August 2016.

http://marketingland.com/google-removes-adsense-3-ads-per-page-limit-focuses-content-ad-balance-189064

Answer (score 3):

I think Google has lifted the maximum of 3 content units per page.

Now they just say that ads should not be more than content. And you won't find the max units rule anywhere in the documentation.

You can read here in valuable inventory.
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ad_limit_per_page

Answer (score 1):

Google has lifted the limit of 3 ads recently. They don't specify the max limit, but they do say that the number should not exceed your content. Here is the official link: [Number of AdSense Ads](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ad_limit_per_page)

Answer (score 0):

Three standard ad units mean that you can use 3 main standard and suggested by google: 1 728x90, 1 336x280 or 1 300x250 and 1 160x600.

Three link units mean that you can get it by create link units in your adsense dashboard.

Search box you know adready.

Comment: Don't include the links of your personal blog/sites. Those can be considered as spam which may cause you penalty

Answer (score 0):

According to Adsense Tos,

You can add upto 3 standard ads /per page (Maximum of 1 300*600 ads size followed by other ads size accept 970x90 ) in addition with 3 link ads unit for adsense Content . These are the Maximum AdSence Ads Per Page for Adsense content.

Comment: Please don't add only cursorily related links to your own blog without disclosing that its your blog.

Answer (score -1):

You can have 3 standard size ads on your page. And I don't recommend you to add any more (not even link ads). In place of that why not adding infolinks, viglink and others?