# google adsense ads not displaying more than 7-8 times in loop

Tags: php, jquery, adsense

As I have page for `<div>` loop in a page. what I need to display is after 5 div (5 data row) I need to Display Google Ad so here is the code :

**Header code :**

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

**Body code :**

```
 <?php if ($gcount%5==0) { ?> 
    <!-- reserve section -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
         data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
         data-ad-slot="xxxx"
         data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
     <script>
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
  <?php } ?>
```

The Problem is In loop Google Ads Display 7-8 times but after that It got Blank Dive block.

And the Pages That I have to display Ads is load by Ajax (lazy loading) By scrolling. Is Google Ads Allow Ads in Ajax or in Lazy loading page ? My Logic is working till 6th page of Ajax loading , but in 7th page Ads are Displaying as Blank Blocks.

Comment: You can find the answer here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247783/maximum-total-google-ads-per-page

Answer (score 2):

Google imposes limits on the number of ads per page. See https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en-GB#Ad_limit_per_page

Comment: Per page ads are only 2 , but with auto load ajax page on scrolling It may work or not ? It work on 2 to 6 page, but not work after 7th page